# How to limit/throttle speed of Views feed?

Tags: views, feeds

I have a Views feed that includes all recent content on my website. I run this through an IFTTT applet to auto-post to Twitter.

Is there a way to throttle how many feed items are added to the feed at once, in order to limit the number of tweets that come out of the IFTTT applet?

For example, if I add 10 pieces of content, I'd like the feed to reflect the first five now, and the next five after fifteen minutes.

ETA: I'm not limiting myself to using only Feeds, other modules or suggestions for a custom module are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible, but not with *just* feeds.

You'll have to implement some sort of queuing, that looks at previously published nodes to determine if the new group of nodes can be added to the feed yet, or if they need to wait.

You should be able to get this working with some clever [rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) and a few [VBO views](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations).

Comment: Thanks, the mention of Rules led me to https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_onceperday, which is close to what I need.

Answer (score 0):

If you're feed is only showing published content, you could use the [Scheduler](https://www.drupal.org/project/scheduler) module to publish your content periodically.